# How do I see my suggested edit, and its current status?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

When making a suggested edit anonymously, I notice that while the Community user shows [lots of approval activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity), there are [zero suggestions, ever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

Assuming I care about a suggestion and would like to see it get somewhere, how do I find out whether it's been rejected or is just stuck in the queue?

In this example, I was correcting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370942/), as the top-rated answer will print the wrong thing for some inputs, such as 0x40000005.  A correct algorithm can be found in Torbjörn Granlund & Peter L. Montgomery "[Division by Invariant Integers Using Multiplication](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.1.2556)" (1994).

Answer (score 3):

Your answer edit was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/326384), it changed too much of the original intent.

Corrections to incorrect answers are better posted as new answers instead. If you do not have the time for that, just leave a comment on the answer with a pointer as to how it is incorrect. Both require you to make an account, though, but you'll get reputation when good answers get upvoted, giving you more options to use Stack Overflow.

Note that anonymous edits are only assigned to the Community User after they have been accepted; while in the editing queue they marked as by "an anonymous user". They are not listed anywhere for anonymous users to see; higher rep users only see them in the approval queue when still pending.

Answer (score 3):

You don't.  If you're interested in tracking the status of a suggestion then you'll need to have an account.  If you create an account and make a non-anonymous suggestion then you will be able to track it.

Answer (score 1):

That list is a list of suggestions the Community user has made, and Community doesn't do that. If you go to the suggestions tab on your own profile, you will see a list of suggestions you've made, including ones that are still pending in the queue. From there you can get a link to a suggestion's individual summary page.

The particular suggestion you referred to was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/326384) for changing too much of the original post

Comment: The suggested edit was made anonymously, and those are owned by the Community user. As such it won't be visible on the OP's account, he / she has *no* account on SO that I could see.

Comment: @MartijnPieters They are? It says "proposed by an anonymous user", not "proposed by Community"

Comment: Yeah, sorry; *accepted* edits are owned by Community. Before that they are just not owned at all, nor listed anywhere for anonymous users to see.